# Redux Saga & Redux Toolkit watcher problem

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

hope you have a nice day!
I am newbie to redux and redux saga and i wanted to ask you all help.

This is the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-wave-3ewyr?file=/src/store.js

The problem is that when i click on increment button the value of "counter" inside the store become 0 then it will be incremented by 1. Clicking on Decremenet and Sum works because they are not using sagas.
Example:
Click on decrement: counter become -1
Click on increment: counter become 0 then 1 (it should be 0 cause we expect to be: -1 + 1)
Anyone can explain me where is the problem?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the final part of your reducer:

```js
default:
  return 0;
```

Since there is no `case` for the `INCREMENT` action, the code execution goes to `default` and resets the counter to zero.

The solution is to return the current state instead:

```js
default:
  return state;
```

Comment: OH right! Sometime the solution is right under our eyes! thank you a lot